# Windows Azure Linux VM Slow Reboot

Tags: linux, azure, ubuntu-12.04

I'm not sure if anyone else has experienced this, but it has been an ongoing problem with Azure since I signed up a little over a month ago.

Rebooting my Linux Virtual Machines take no less than 15 to 30 minutes, every time.  These are "stock" Ubuntu 12.04 images, nothing fancy on them, not even a web server or database for the most part.  But the time they take until becoming accessible through SSH is mind-numbingly long compared to other cloud services such as Amazon.

Furthermore, on three separate occasions, the servers came back up with endpoints (ports) changed internally (connections refused) and two of those instances became completely inaccessible for reasons unknown, thus prompting me to recreate everything from scratch.  The other instance referenced above became accessible through the configured endpoint port in about an additional 10 to 15 minutes, well after the Azure dashboard showed it as "Running."

Has anyone else had this issue with Linux on Azure?  Is there any way to mitigate it?

Comment: I'm not sure if this can helps you:
http://serverfault.com/questions/438606/my-linux-azure-server-hangs-and-it-takes-lots-of-time-to-reboot

Comment: That's actually very informative, at least it shows others are experiencing the same thing.  Too bad Microsoft hasn't done anything about it yet.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To everyone reading this, it appears that this issue has been fixed by Microsoft in the past year. My current Ubuntu Linux VM's reboot within seconds each time, without any difficulty.